# Find digits $x$, $y$, $z$, and $p$ such that $(xyzp)_{10}=4\cdot (pzyx)_{10}$

Tags: arithmetic, decimal-expansion

Given that equation $xyzp=4\cdot pzyx$ is valid, how do I solve showing my work clearly? By trial and error the valid answers are $x=8,y=7,z=1,p=2$. These are the only conditions provided.

Comment: Is everything needed in your question?

Comment: Does your question mean, "how to solve the problem without trial and error?"

Comment: I suspect that the variables are supposed to be *digits* (not positive reals), and we are talking about concatentation rather than multiplication.

Comment: @Gerry: Which makes the $4$ even more confusing...

Comment: @Zev, sorry, the $4$ is a factor, the variables are digits. $4\times 2178=8712$.

Comment: @Zev, shouldn't we have confirmation from OP before making such an edit?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because "If and only if the (whys) are answered because here take it I never gave out my answers."

Answer (score 4):

Here's a start (assuming I have the right interpretation of the problem in the comments).

1. $p$ must be even (why?)
2. $p\lt3$ (why?)
3. So $x$ is 8 or 9 (why?)
4. But $x$ can't be 9 (why?)

Comment: If and only if the (whys) are answered because here take it I never gave out my answers.

Comment: I'm sorry --- I have no idea what you mean by that.

Answer (score 1):

p z y x

### × 4

x y z p
x × 4 = p in unit place. 
similarly p × 4 = x

4 digit number × 4 gives 4 digit answer, p < 3
But p = 4 × x is even
so p = 2 and x = 8
so it becomes
2 z y 8

### × 4

8 y z 2
it shows that there is no carry forward in z × 4
so z must be 1
2 1 y 8

### × 4

8 y 1 2
so you can calsukate y
8 × 4 = 32 ----- 3 c/f.
y × 4 + 3 = 1 in unit place 
so y = 7

### x = 8,y = 7,z = 1,p = 2